# How to turn off Logger in external library component

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm using a component from an external library and it is sending debug messages to the console I've created. Is there a way for me to turn these off? There is a debug option that I set to false but it is still tracing out messages. It might have to do with me adding my own logging target.

Comment: By default, there is not. It would have to be built into the library itself using conditionals (`if(allowTrace){trace("blah")}`) so you are likely out of luck.

Comment: Have you read this? http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=logging_09.html Would the TraceTarget class help?  I'm not sure if it is global to the app; or can be used selectively in components.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to suppress those messages, yet still show your own, if you set the [filter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/logging/AbstractTarget.html#filters) property of the log target. It's actually discussed on the page that @Reboog711 linked to.

```
var logTarget:TraceTarget = new TraceTarget();
logTarget.filters = ["your.fully.qualified.package.name", "can.use.wildcards.too.*"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know to turn off the logging for the whole application is by increasing the level property of TraceTarget above 1000